# Another word for not present

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to know another word for "Not present"
Here would be the example sentence.

> All the students were here except Joshua, who was not present.

Comment: What about *absent*?

Comment: That could work, but I'm looking for a more complicated word.

Comment: I'm sure we can come up with something more convoluted. Can you describe the connotation you're aiming for? Do we want *playing hookie* or *unaccounted for*?

Comment: This isn't a "word-choice" question (that chooses between words in a defined list); it's a "single-word-request" question, which has its own criteria as set out in the tag wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*who was not **available***

*who was not **there***

*who was not **of the party***

*who **didn't materialize***

*who **didn't congeal** for the /situation/party/event/* :-)

Comment: Didn't materialize made me laugh. The rest of them should fit in great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

...who was **absent**;
...who was **truant**.

Answer (score 1):

...who was somewhere else

...who didn't show

...who was away

...who was missing

...who was on leave

...who was gone

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to be 'complicated' and sound sophisticated you could say it in Latin:  'except for Joshua who was *in absentia*'